# Loop through specific folder of csv, merging the 1st row of each into one workbook

Tags: vba, loops, csv

I've looked through several posts and can't seem to find a suitable answer - similar, but not quite what I'm looking for.

I would like some code that loops through a series of csv-files (~ 200 at a time) within a specific folder. It needs to import/copy the values of the first row of each of these csv-files to one (main) workbook. These csv-file-names are numerical (eg 20140213075458) any files that does not meet this criteria (14 characters, numbers only AND FileFormat = csv) should not be considered.

Any guidance will be much appreciated!

Comment: `I would like some code that loops through a series of csv-files (~ 200 at a time) within a specific folder.` this statement will raise a lot of eyebrows. so if you have somehow made any attemp in coding, post the code here. Also better if you can provide sample data (not actual data but a replica of it).

Answer (score 0):

Add the Microsoft Scripting Runtime library to your project and use Use `FileSystemObject` class to loop through all files. You can use the `Like` operator to check if file name matches your criteria.

Answer (score 0):

i think [this](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/addins/rdbmerge.htm) add-in might help you for sure. 
RDBMerge used to Merge Data from Multiple Excel Workbooks,
csv and xml files into a Summary Workbook.

Answer (score 0):

I am just going to outline the operations you need to do. You can work from that.

1. Get the filename of each file in each folder: `fname = Dir(Your_Folder_Path)`
2. Initialize file read counter: `i=1`
3. Loop through all files in folder:
   `Do While fname <> "" 'Loop all files in folder`
4. Check your conditions:

   ```
   Extension = Split(fname, ".")(Ubound(Split(fname, "."))) 'Extract extension of file
   Name = Split(fname, ".")(Ubound(Split(fname, "."))-1) 'Extract name of file without extension
   If Extension = "csv" And Len(Name) = 14 And IsNumeric(Name) Then 'Check csv, length of name 14 and numeric name
   ```
5. Open csv, read first line and close it:

   ```
   Open Your_Folder_Path & fname For Input As #f1
   Line Input #f1, csvFirstLine
   Close #f1
   ```
6. Put data in workbook:

   ```
   ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i).Value = csvFirstLine 'Put line in corresponding row
   ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i).TextToColumns Comma:=True 'Separate data by comma
   i=i+1 'File counter +1
   ```
7. Exit ifs and close loops: `End If` `Loop`